# In React audio tag not working, instead it just displays the link

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In React I am getting the source file dynamically through an api call.
`<audio src={rec.data2} type="audio/mp3" controls autoplay />`
It is not displaying the usual play button with volume control, instead it just displays the link. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src={rec.data2} type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

[w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp) explain it :

> Definition and Usage The  tag is used to embed sound content in
> a document, such as music or other audio streams.
>
> The  tag contains one or more  tags with different
> audio sources. The browser will choose the first source it supports.
>
> The text between the  and  tags will only be displayed
> in browsers that do not support the  element.
>
> There are three supported audio formats in HTML: MP3, WAV, and OGG.